# ¿Cómo convertir un PDOStatement en JSON e imprimirlo?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, xampp

Estoy implementando la siguiente función en PHP con la que deseo retornar un arreglo dependiendo de un id, pero al momento de convertir el array a json e imprimirlo no me aparece el resultado.

```
public static function getAllDebtorsByUser(int $id) : array {
    $query = "SELECT id_debtor Id, name_debtor Name, address_debtor Address, phone_debtor Phone from debtors where user_debtor = :i;";
    $sth = Connection::select($query, ["i" => $id]); //Regresa un PDOStatement
    if($sth->rowCount() > 0) {
        while($row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            $debtors[] = $row;
        }
        return $debtors;
    } else
        return [];
}
```

Utilicé el siguiente código para convertir de array a JSON. No me marca errores, pero tampoco me muestra el resultado a menos que quiera mostrar una sola columna en vez de 3.

**Ejemplo**

Código para imprimir:

```
echo json_encode(Debtor::getAllDebtorsByUser(1)); //La función está dentro de una clase llamada Debtor
```

Query:

```
SELECT id_debtor Id from debtors where user_debtor = :i;
```

Resultado:

```
[
    {
        "Id": "1"
    },
    {
        "Id": "2"
    }
]
```

Teniendo las 3 columnas que necesito y utilizando la función de PHP *print_r* me muestra el resultado correcto, pero lo que necesito es que el JSON se vea.

**Ejemplo:**

Código para imprimir:

```
print_r(Debtor::getAllDebtorsByUser(1));
```

Query:

```
SELECT id_debtor Id, name_debtor Name, address_debtor Address, phone_debtor Phone from debtors where user_debtor = :i;
```

Resultado:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Id] => 1
            [Name] => Debtor 1
            [Address] => Dir 1
            [Phone] => Tel 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Id] => 2
            [Name] => Debtor 2
            [Address] => Dir 2
            [Phone] => Tel 2
        )

)
```

De modo que utilizando echo `json_encode()` para imprimir no me funciona a menos que la consulta tenga una sola columna.

**Versiones de software**

PHP: 7.2.12

MySQL: 5.7.24

XAMPP: 3.2.2

SO: Windows 10

Answer (score 1):

Por lo que veo [json_encode](https://secure.php.net/manual/es/function.json-encode.php) trae una opción para indicar la profundidad del array que tiene que procesar, en tu caso seguramente sea una profundidad de 2.

Te pongo el código de prueba en el que lo he probado:

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php

$res = array(1,2,3,4);
$res['SegundoNivel'] = array(5,6,7);
$res['SegundoNivel']['TercerNivel'] = array(8,9,10);


$json = json_encode($res,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT,1);
$json1 = json_encode($res,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT,2);
$json2 = json_encode($res,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT,3);

echo "Profundidad 1 \n";
echo($json);

echo "Profundidad 2 \n";
echo ($json1);

echo "Profundidad 3 el correcto\n";
echo($json2);
```

El resultado sería:

```
Profundidad 1 
Profundidad 2 
Profundidad 3 el correcto
{
    "0": 1,
    "1": 2,
    "2": 3,
    "3": 4,
    "SegundoNivel": {
        "0": 5,
        "1": 6,
        "2": 7,
        "TercerNivel": [
            8,
            9,
            10
        ]
    }
}
```